# Why are extra newlines there if pasting into plaintext context 'p' tags copied from browser?

Tags: html, browser, newline, copy-paste

Consider the example

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>In sed diam vitae justo laoreet ullamcorper.</p>
<p>Donec vehicula tellus vitae ligula finibus congue.</p>
<p>In ut sapien consectetur, efficitur ante et, interdum leo.</p>
```

It is rendered in a browser as expected with each paragraph on its own line:

[image: rendered]

Now when copying this text and pasting it into any plaintext context extra newlines appear:

[image: extra newlines]

Should you paste this into formatting-aware application (say LibreOffice Writer) no extra newlines this time:

[image: no extra newlines]

And finally by copying this from LibreOffice Writer to the first mentioned plaintext editor we can get rid of these extra newlines:

[image: got rid]

Tried copying from Firefox and Chromium with the same results, so I assume it is universal among browsers.

Those screenshots were made on GNU/Linux with Geany and LibreOffice Writer. Absolutely the same behaviour is observed under MS Windows with Notepad++ and MS Office Word.

The questions are:

1. Why is it that newlines are added if pasting into plaintext application?
2. Is there any way to get rid of them if pasting into plaintext application?

Comment: Does it happen the same in different plaintext editors? That looks like how the editor is interpreting the `<p>` tag.

Comment: @freginold It happen all-alike across every plaintext editor. Even Windows alternatives observe the same behaviour. I'll update the question to include this finding.

Comment: can you give some examples of programs it happens in?  Windows Notepad doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: @freginold Windows 7 Notepad does also add extra newlines

Comment: Are you pasting the source (with the `<p>` tags) or the rendered output into Notepad?

Comment: @freginold Ofcourse I copy-paste the rendered output. Why would I copy the source code? Copying source code as a plain text will not have any side effects obviously.

Comment: Your question did not specify which you were using. Since it's an unusual problem, I wanted to make sure.

Comment: @freginold Quoting the question: "It is rendered......." and then "Now when copying *this* text....".

Comment: "*when copying this text*" could mean the rendered text or the source text you included above that. A little specificity goes a long way.

Comment: @freginold Nobody is calling `source code` as `source text`

Comment: It's the text you included in your question. We're not looking at a rendered HTML page; we're looking at the text that you put into your question.

Comment: @freginold saying "We're not looking at a rendered HTML page" is equivalent to saying "Well, we're not looking at your question at all" given that "rendered HTML page" is in fact the image just below "It is rendered in a browser as expected with each paragraph on its own line:". Lets make it straight. I put source code in my question, named it *example*, so any time I need to refer to it I would do so by referring to *example source code* and no other way. When I put an image of a rendered text, I no longer refer to *example source code* as context changed to *this text you see just above*.

Comment: If you had put half the effort into your question that you put into that comment, we could have avoided this back-and-forth.

Comment: @freginold I would prefer not to put my efforts into explaining obvious things, besides that would needlessly lengthen the question

Comment: Okay, whatever works for you.